# AD620 DC offset

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier

I'm trying to use AD620 to amplify a signal coming from a piezo sensor. I've connected it as the following:

[image]

Where the sensor's terminals are connected between 2 and 3. Vref is GND and RG is 10k.I'm connecting the negative terminal of the sensor to GND as well. I couldn't draw it using the circuit editor as I haven't found AD620 part.I connected the output to the oscilloscope (pin6 +terminal, and pin 5 -terminal). I get a DC offset of around 160 mV to 0V all the time regardless of what Vref is.

1- I want to know hy does this happen and how can we control the offset?

2- Is it possible to operate it with a single 9 V supply where we connect V- to GND, v+ to 9V and Vref to say 2V? I want to left the signal to the positive side using the DC offset.

NOTE: I'm using DC coupling on the oscilloscope to see the offset
NOTE2: All grounds are connected to the circuit's ground. I'm using a bench supply and it's ground is also connected to the circuit's ground.

Thank you

Comment: why aren't the sensor's terminals connected to pins 2 and 3 like they're supposed to be?

Comment: @Neil_UK That was a typo, I've fixed it, I also connected the ground terminal of the oscilloscope to Vref, now it shows a160mv DC offset even if I set Vref to 5 V

Comment: negative sensor terminal is still connected to ground? Does the sensor have 3 terminals. Add the sensor to the schematic.

Comment: @Neil_UK It only has two terminals, I uploaded the full picture now

Comment: OK, datahseet time. It's just occured to me that a piezo is probably high resistance output. What iis it, link the data sheet. What's its output resistance. What the input bias current for a 620? What gain does a 10k rg give the 620?

Comment: The link for the senso's data sheet is http://www.cui.com/product/resource/ceb-35d26.pdf   the link for the AD620's datasheet is  http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD620.pdf. The gain fr 10 k resistor is 5.94. How do I find the input bias current?

Comment: @Neil_UK quite sure it's like that. Piezo is just a capacitance, DC open circuit. Isra, you just lack bias path to IA "upper" input

Comment: @carloc if you mean for Vref, I built an op amp voltage divider and connected it between 6v and ground, its output should be 3 V Which I connected to Vref on the AD620, but again the result is the same.

Comment: How do I find the input bias current? Look in the data sheet under 'input bias current'.

Comment: @IUsra: why do you use an Instrumentation Amplifier at all? Why not an ordinary OpAmp? Aren't you free to have to piezo referenced to GND?

Comment: @curd because I'm using it with a biosignal (heartbeat). I've already built a n op amp circuit but it was more complicated with several stages and noise. I've read that Instrumentation amplifiers are more suitable for this application, and when I use it it won't need many extra stages. The offset is because I will be using a microcontroller which does not take negative input, so I thought of raising the signal to be all positive.

Comment: @Isra: why does "using it with a biosignal" require using an Instrumentation Amplifier?

Comment: Because the signal range is very low, and instrumentation amplifiers offer better amplification with minimum noise...http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/practical-uses-of-instrumentation-amplifiers/

Comment: Instrumentation amplifiers are needed when you cannot GND-reference the signal you are measuring. And *some* biomedical applications may have this restriction (e.g. measuring ECG where you connect electodes to an electrically floating body). That doesn't mean, however, that it be useful to use an instrumentation amplifier in *any* biomedical application. Especially in the case you describe I don't see a reason why the piezo element cannot be referenced to any  potential you want, e.g. GND. In your case an InAmp won't give you better Signal/Noise ratio. It just makes it more complicated.

Comment: @Curd Thank you for the great explanation, I get it now. But when I connect the two terminals of the piezo sensor to the inputs of the In-Amp (as in the picture above), wouldn't it treat it like a normal sensor and eliminate the common noise? . I've read that for example AD8221 blocks the 50 Hz noise which will be very beneficial in my case (I used AD620 since it's the closest to it). I can see clearer results with AD620 and it's only a single stage circuit which reduces the size of my circuit and the error chances after soldering, isn't that better?

Comment: As much as I see neither AD8221 nor AD620 have special 50Hz filters. Concerning noise: I'd concentrate on picking up noise in the first place, e.g. by placing the amplifier close to the source, by shielding, by using twisted pair wires etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AD620 has a typical input bias current of 0.5nA, 1nA max.

A piezo sensor tends to have a very high output resistance, looking more or less like a capacitor, so with no explicit DC path for the bias currents to flow, these will generate an offset voltage. That the offset is limited to what it is shows the piezo is a bit leaky.

With a gain of 6, and 160mV output voltage, that's an input offset of 27mV, way more than the AD620 typical of 15uV. An input offset of 27mV at 0.5nA indicates in the order of 50Mohm as the piezo leakage, which sounds reasonable, and is consistent with the piezo specification of 20Mohm minimum.

You need an explicit DC path for this bias current to flow. One choice (not the best) is a high value resistor to ground, say 1M. It has to be high enough not to load the piezo, but low enough to control the offset. 1M would give 0.5mV offset at 0.5nA, which would gain up to 3mV at the output. The piezo claims an terminal impedance of 300ohms at resonance, which will drive 1M easily, if you're using it at resonance. It also claims a capacitance of 30nF, which is down to 5Hz with a 1M load, if it behaves as a simple high pass filter.

A better choice is to remove the ground connection from one input, and connect 1Mohm from *both* inputs to ground. This reduces the DC offset further, as the typical input bias current now flows through *both* resistors, balancing the input. The expected residual offset is now the input *offset* current. The input resistance presented to the sensor is now 2Mohms, not 1Mohm, as it's a differential input.

The AD620 amplifier, with its REF input terminal for offsetting the output, seems to be causing some sort of conceptual problem with oscilloscope and power supply grounding.

The AD620 inputs and outputs, including REF, must always stay clear of the rails by around 2v (in round numbers).

It's still not clear from the OP, after several questions in comments, whether his power supply is grounded to his oscilloscope, though with the difficulties he's having, that looks likely.

The simplest, 'ride-the-horse-in-the-direction-it's-going' way to use such an amplifier, is with dual supplies, like this. This way, it doesn't matter whether supply ground and scope ground actually imply a galvanic connection between the two or not.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhNH5l.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If instead, you want to use a single supply, with an active reference, then you may run into trouble if you don't know your ground from your elbow.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2firFgJ.png)</sup>

If the power supply is a 12v battery, so floating, then it's possible to ground the reference generator terminal. Now the oscilloscope can read the amplifier output +/-4v with respect to ground.

If the power supply is a mains connected supply, with the negative terminal connected to safety earth, and through the distribution strip back to the scope ground, then if we connect the scope input ground to the reference generator output, it will short the reference to the supply negative terminal.

People often, and unsafely, handle this problem by disconnecting the safety earth of either the scope or the power supply in the plug. It's obvious why that's unsafe. It's also not very good from a signal integrity point of view, as the capacitance of either instrument from circuits to ground, as they've not been designed to be quiet expecting them to be disconnected, often conducts a lot of internally generated noise into to the rest of the ground loop, so processor hash, mains hum, mains diode rectifier switching harmonics, that sort of thing.

The correct ways to deal with this are to ...

a) use a battery supply, or a power supply that's designed with a floating output.

b) ground the scope to the supply ground, and use a dual input, one to the amp output, one to the amp REF, and use the scope's Y1-Y2 function (99% of oscilloscopes with 2 input channels implement this) to see the differential signal between them.

c) Ground the scope to the supply ground. On DC coupling, the scope will read the signal, riding on top of the mid-rail REF offset. On AC coupling, the offset will rejected, and the scope sensitivity can be turned up to see the signal at higher gain.

Comment: Yes I understand you now. I've tried what you suggested, and the output is fixed with 0 DC offset. Yet when I connect Vref to 3V, this doesn't change the reference on the oscilloscope. I'm getting the 3 V from an op amp voltage divider (2 100k ohm resistors). The Op amp is TL072, and I used it with a 6V input and 0 as -Vs.I also get no response when I tap on it. Do you have an idea on why this is happening?

Comment: What TL072 op amp????????? Draw **ALL** your circuit on the schematic. Geez. Check the sensor straight onto the oscilloscope, do you get a reading when you tap? Connect Vref to ground. What's this with trying to make it complicated? Update your OP, your question, with any information you've been keeping secret, I'm not going to trawl through comments trying to piece it all together.

Comment: I was just using TL072 because its less noisy than Lm741. I changed to a simple LM741 and I can see a change when I tap, but I still have zero offset. I've checked the sensor straight to the oscilloscope and its working. I'll edit the circuit now and upload it.

Comment: If you connect pin 5 to the ground terminal on your scope, then there's a good chance that connection is shorting pin 5 to ground. So, you haven't finished drawing schematics yet, have you? Show **ALL** connections, including whether your scope has a DC path to earth ground via its input and mains lead, and whether that ground also connects to your power supply, and so your 620 -ve supply terminal. Note that a 620 won't work properly when the reference terminal is within 1.6v of either rail. Update the text in your OP to match the diagram.

Comment: The simplest route is to use a balanced supply, with input 1Ms and the ref terminal and the scope ground all connected to ground. Once you have that working to your satisfaction, then you can start trying to use single power supply operation. However, with a grounded scope and single-rail operation, you will only see half your output waveform unless you bias it about a not-ground voltage. Then you need to connect your scope so it reads with respect to not-ground. Often, we use two input channels, connected to signal, and its reference, and use the scope's V1+(-V2) function to see the signal.

Comment: I've updated the circuit again, the ground from the scope is connected to Vref, so if Vref is GND so will the scope's ground be. I tried it with both single and double supply, the offset is still zero. When I used the single supply, I connected V- to the circuit's ground. I don't get you, do you mean that the negative input terminal should be my scope's ground?

Comment: The key question is 'is the scope's ground connected to the power supply ground?' Are you using floating batteries for your PSU, or a mains-connected bench supply? If the latter, is the -ve terminal, or the ground, or nothing, connected to the scope ground? In other words, is your scope shorting your Vref to ground? The best way will be to connect your scope's ground to ... wait for it ... circuit ground, at least while you're trying to debug things. The scope will read the Vref as a big DC offset, but that's the sort of thing you want to know. AC couple for more sensitivity, during debug.

Comment: yes you are right! I was viewing the signal with respect to Vref all this time when I should be measuring it with respect to ground, this caused the fixed zero offset. I tried it with 9V and 5V supply voltage (from the bench) and it always gave an offset of around Vs/2. Now if I wanted to make this single supply, it's not as sensitive as it is when it's double supply. Is that how it should be? Thank you very much, I appreciate your efforts

Comment: The amplifier gain will have the same sensitivity to the piezo input whether single or dual supply. The oscilloscope connection will be easier to get wrong with single supply. Notice I haven't used the word 'this' or 'it' as I'm not sure what you're referring to.

Comment: when using single supply, why should the oscilloscope connections be changed? I mean the supply shouldn't affect the output if it's sufficient right?

Comment: You're still having trouble with that concept of **ALL**, aren't you. I've updated the answer as I need diagrams to show what I'm talking about. **ALL** connections means including the instrument grounds. Anywhere there is a wire, show it, or at least account for it.

Comment: I don't know what else to add, I've tried my best to mention every detail about my circuit. My grounds are all connected to the circuit's ground, including the bench supply's ground and the oscilloscope's ground. The biasing resistors are also connected to the same ground as I've shown in the picture.

Comment: well read the diagrams in my answer, that shows you what the extra ground connections contribute to the working, or otherwise, of your circuit.

Answer (score 1):

As said in one of the comments: I don't see the need for an instrumentation amplifier. 
Instead I'd use a cheap simple dual OpAmp with high impedance inputs (for a fraction of the price), e.g. TL082 like shown in the schematic below:

If required R4 can be decreased for higher gain.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJA1XJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Yes and I wish I'd learned that earlier. May I ask what's the purpose of the 10nF capacitor? and why did you connect R5 between the two ends of the sensor?

Comment: The capacitor is there to reduce (filter) noise of the reference voltage. 1M resistor is there because a piezo element is a very high impedance source or like a source that is AC coupled, i.e. the upper terminal could be floating anywhere. The resistor makes sure the signal is close to the reference voltage (maybe smaller values can be used). (BTW: I realized that operating voltage range of TL082 requires at little bit more than 9V (10V); so another J-FET OpAmp should be used; but it shouldn't be a problem to find one)